# Page Scrolling Effect With Ajax How Data Is Loaded Into The Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am loading data from a mysql table into a html table. I am using AJAX php Jquery to accomplish this. I need to make sure that the way I built this will work regardless of how much data is in the table.

Right now I am working with a table that is 5000 rows long but there will eventually be 88000 rows in this table.

I know if I load all the data on page load this could end up bogging down the server and the load time of the page.

My question is the way my logic is now will it load all the results into the $results and only query the needed amount of rows because it is paginated. Or even though it is paginated is my webpage taking every row in the whole database for load time.

if the whole table is being loaded how can I change the query to only load the data when needed. It loads on page scroll.

Also I need to write a search function. Since the data is paginated would I search the data in $results or query the table with separate search functions? Which way would provide less load times which would cause a bad experience for my user?

The AjAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var busy = true;
var limit = 5;
var offset = 0;
var assetPath = "<?php echo $assetPath ?>"

function displayRecords(lim, off) {
  jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          url: assetPath,
          data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off,
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
            $('#loader_image').show();
          },
          success: function(html) {
            $("#productResults").append(html);
            $('#loader_image').hide();
            if (html == "") {
             $("#loader_message").html('<button data-atr="nodata" class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show()
            } else {
             $("#loader_message").html('Loading... Please wait <img src="http://www.wuno.com/monstroid/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/LoaderIcon.gif" alt="Loading">').show();
            }
            window.busy = false;

          }
        });
}

(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
if (busy == true) {
  displayRecords(limit, offset);
  busy = false;
}
});
})( jQuery );



(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
          // make sure u give the container id of the data to be loaded in.
          if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#productResults").height() && !busy) {
            offset = limit + offset;
         displayRecords(limit, offset);

          }
});
});
})( jQuery );
});
</script>
```

This is how I am querying the database

```
$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 5;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
try {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo '<tr class="invent">';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_product'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_alternates'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_description'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_onhand'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_condition'] . '</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';   
  }
}
```

Comment: Your mechanism with the LIMIT and OFFSET parameters in the SQL query does part of the job well. I don't see how the _lim_ and _offs_  parameters are updated on the client side. I'd suggest you transfer the data as a json object _{lim:$limit, offs: $offset, htm:html-text}_, and add _dataType: "json",_ to the _jQuery.ajax_ call.

Comment: Re: search function. I believe the user would mean to search througout the data table and not only within the (limited) results (what he/she also could do by an offline page search in the browser). Thus, the only way for a search would be to modify your SQL statement and, maybe, use the LIKE keyword.

Comment: I had to add an answer for it's too much of code. Please see there what I mean with the JSON approach. Note: I didn't test the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By transferring a JSON object from the server the *limit*, *offset* and *html* (and maybe others lime *status_messsage*, etc.) values could be transferred to the client at the same time.

On the client side I meant something like this:

```
var limit = 5;
var offset = 0;
var assetPath = "<?php echo $assetPath ?>"

function displayRecords(lim, off) {
  jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      url: assetPath,
      dataType: "json",                         // We expect to receive a json object
      data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off,
      cache: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
        $('#loader_image').show();
      },
      success: function(json) {
        limit = json.lim;                       // corr to $output['lim']
        offset = json.offs;                     // corr to $output['offs']
        $("#productResults").append(json.html); // corr to $output['html']
        $('#loader_image').hide();
        if (json.html == "") {
         $("#loader_message").html('<button data-atr="nodata" class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show()
        } else {
         $("#loader_message").html('Loading... Please wait <img src="http://www.wuno.com/monstroid/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/LoaderIcon.gif" alt="Loading">').show();
        }
        window.busy = false;

      }
    });
}
```

...and on the server side:

```
$limit = (intval($_REQUEST['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_REQUEST['limit'] : 5;
$offset = (intval($_REQUEST['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_REQUEST['offset'] : 0;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
// Make sure to handle invalid offset values properly, 
// as they are not validated from the last request.

// Prepare the $output structure (will become a json object string)
$output = array(
  'lim'=>$limit,
  'offs'=>$offset+$limit,
  'html'=>''
);
try {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  $output['html'] .= $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    $output['html'] .= '<tr class="invent">';  
    $output['html'] .= '<td>' . $res['wuno_product'] . '</td>';  
    $output['html'] .= '<td>' . $res['wuno_alternates'] . '</td>';  
    $output['html'] .= '<td>' . $res['wuno_description'] . '</td>';  
    $output['html'] .= '<td>' . $res['wuno_onhand'] . '</td>';  
    $output['html'] .= '<td>' . $res['wuno_condition'] . '</td>';  
    $output['html'] .= '</tr>';   
  }
}
// Now encode $output as a json object (string) and send it to the client
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: It would allow you to, at the same time, transfer the html code together with the limit and offset values in one "echo" from the server. So, the _offset_ variable, which is used when the (next, scroll down) request is sent, would be updated and correspond to the last SQL access.

Comment: I'd suggest you call the client side script manually with the appropriate parateres (GET) and verify what it echoes. I changed $_GET to $_REQUEST (covering $_GET and $_POST)  for this to work. On the client side I use a debugging feature of the browser, allowing to set breakpoints and to inspect the result.

Comment: Hey i have to ask, you did this 
$output['html'] .= $ex->getMessage(); won't that only happen if there is an exception? cause its in the try catch.

Comment: Yes. It is sent as part of the json object to the client, which takes it as html text. It replaces your "echo" statement like the others do.

Comment: I added a _header()_ statement and parameters to the _json\_encode_ statement.

Comment: haha thanks a lot man. I really hate to keep bothering you cause i Know you were just helping but I really would love to know how to make this work.  being able to work with json would make me happy. the headers still dont load data and I still get json not defined.

Comment: Does something like this look like it would help? data = JSON.parse(data); im not sure what i would parse. is it always data that comes back?

Comment: hmm, I don't think this helps. "data" or "json" in your case is a Javascript json object already and can be used as such. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Added a reduced example of the JSON / AJAX mechanism as a separate answer. I've tested this one.

Comment: thanks man. It appears the same thing really. I am not understanding why it wont work with my code... It works perfect till i add your code then i get nothing.

Comment: Actually no it does not.

Comment: That's really strange. I assume you have modified the _jquery-1.4.3.min.js_ and _assetPath_ definitions. I've tested it using the Chrome, Thunderbird, and Internet Explorer browsers. All gave the result I show in the answer!

Comment: hmm maybe its cause its a wordpress site? A lot of things are annoying about that. Like wraping jquery in functions cause they keep $ out of the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

I do this exact thing you want on my site http://www.flixnetforme.com/ where as you can see as you scroll to the bottom of the page the next set of records is loaded. I have over 150,000 records but it only loads 36 at a time when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

The way you want to do this is is by loading your first initial records through ajax and not hardcode them into the page.

**index.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var last_id;
    if (last_id === undefined) {
        genres = $("#genres").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/getmorefirst.php?",
            data: "genres="+ genres,
            success: function(data) {
                $( ".append" ).append(data);
            }
        });
    };
};

<html><div class="append"></div></html>
```

In this example when the user gets to the page and is loaded it calls `getmorefirst.php` and return the first records.

- `getmorefirst.php` is a file that will load the first set amount of records you want to show when the user gets to the page. In my case I load 36 records at a time when a user scrolls to the bottom of my page.

**getmorefirst.php**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 36"
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $last_id = $row['ID'];
    echo '<div>'.$row['column'].'</div>';
    echo '<div style="display:none" class="last_id" id="'.$last_id.'"';
}
```

The `last_id` div is important so that ajax will know the last record sent and which one to pick up after when it loads the next set of 36 records.

`.append` is the div where I am appending the data from ajax when the user its the bottom.

`.last_id` is your key to knowing how to load the next set of records. In whatever order you send the records back its important that ajax knows the last `ID` of the record loaded so it knows where to start loading the next time ajax calls for more records. In my case when the users scrolls to the bottom of the page.

**when user scrolls to bottom of index.php**

```
if($(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        last_id = $(".last_id:last").attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/getmore.php?",
            data: "last_id="+ last_id,
            success: function(data) {
                $( ".append" ).append(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
};
```

`last_id = $(".last_id:last").attr("id");` will get the last `ID` sent.

`data: "last_id="+ last_id,` will send the last id to `getmore.php` so it knows the last id of the record sent.

**getmore.php**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID > '$last_id' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 36"
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $last_id = $row['ID'];
    echo '<div>'.$row['column'].'</div>';
    echo '<div style="display:none" class="last_id" id="'.$last_id.'"';
}
```

As you can see `getmore.php` will return the next 36 records but AFTER the `last_id` sent.

Hope this make sense and gives you a start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reduced example of the JSON / AJAX mechanism that I have tested:

### HTML (file *test.html*)

```
<html>

<head>
<!-- THE NEXT LINE MUST BE MODIFIED -->
<script src="../jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var limit = 5;
var offset = 0;
// THE NEXT LINE MUST BE MODIFIED
var assetPath = "http://www.example.com/stackoverflow/test.php"

function displayRecords(lim, off) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: assetPath,
        dataType: "json",                   // We expect to receive a json object
        data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#content").html("");
        },
        success: function(json) {
            limit = json.lim;                       // corr to $output['lim']
            offset = json.offs;                     // corr to $output['offs']
            $("#content").html(json.html);
            window.busy = false;
        }
    }); 
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div onclick="displayRecords(limit,offset); return false;" style="cursor:pointer">Click to Call</div>
</body>

</html>
```

### PHP (file *test.php*)

```
<?php
$limit = (intval($_REQUEST['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_REQUEST['limit'] : 5;
$offset = (intval($_REQUEST['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_REQUEST['offset'] : 0;

// Prepare the $output structure (will become a json object string)
$output = array(
'lim'=>$limit,
'offs'=>$offset+$limit,
'html'=>''
);

$output['html'] .= '<span style="color:red;">limit='.$output['lim'].', offset='.$output['offs'].'</span>';

// Now encode $output as a json object (string) and send it to the client
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

### Result

[image: 1st time]
1st time

[image: 2nd time]
2nd time

[image]
nth time

Comment: I wish I could use JSON on my site but with that many records I am afraid :)

Comment: I don't think json will be a problem of performance or size really. Json is only used for the interoperation between client and server. And has the advantage on the client side of accepting structured data, not only html data. So the offset parameter can be updated and sent as parameter correctly with every request. But, the number of records does not seem to me being a problem.

Comment: maybe I will try it, Im just guessing my filesize of my JSON file would be in the 100+ MB

Comment: Since you are only selecting a limited portion of the whole table there should be no problem. Database systems are designed to hold huge amounts of data. While selecting just a portion of it the memory usage is restricted too. And on the client side there should be no problem if you handle and display a couple, up to 50 or 100 tuples together. I'd - of course, avoid endlessly *add* lines to a DIV or similar html element. Of course, if you *really* must transmit 100+ MB, the transmission time would be inacceptable.